# Git - Only add files with changed file permissions

Tags: git, file-permissions, git-add

I have a lot of files where only the file permissions are different. But some files are actually modified.

I would like to add all files where only the file permissions are changed into its own commit.

### `git --version`

```
git version 1.8.3.1
```

### `git diff` output:

```
diff --git a/.htaccess b/.htaccess
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
diff --git a/.htaccess.sample b/.htaccess.sample
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
etc...
```

### `git diff --name-status`

```
M       .htaccess
M       .htaccess.sample
M       robots.txt
M       index.php
etc...
```

### Get all files that have changed

```
git diff -G. --name-status
```

Output:

```
M       robots.txt
M       index.php
```

But how to add only the files with changed permissions, so these can be committed?

Edit:

### `git diff-files`

```
100755 100644 fd0fa6002522f4f4bc46e4339671a6ea99969371 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      .htaccess
:100755 100644 383313a383445374f63364cd1985753e86418d04 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      .htaccess.sample
:100644 100644 e09ab6b6b0cf13a895d00ec97dae12d8ba2c364b 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      robots.txt
:100755 100644 56bdb6c86654bdba26b750d36db17b5e15279c86 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M      index.php
etc...
```

The git diff-files output look like something I could work with. What I have atm...

```
# Get all files that have changed content (save to ../found.list file)
$ git diff -G. --name-status | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 > ../found.list

# Get the diff-files that not have changed content
# This list holds all files that have changed permissions, but have no changed content
# so these are the files that need to be committed
$ git diff-files | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 | grep -Fxvf ../found.list

# Check if it worked
$ git diff-files | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 | wc -l
14951
$ git diff-files | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 | grep -Fxvf ../found.list | wc -l
14935
$ git diff -G. --name-status | wc -l
16
```

This command seems to work. But I think there will be simpler ways to do it.

```
git diff-files | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 | grep -Fxvf ../found.list | while read x; do git add $x; done
```

Comment: I'd recommend to play around `git status --porcelain=n` — please see the manual page on that command. Basically, it's able to generate a machine-parsable output, from which you could grep out only the bits interesting to you.

Comment: `git status --porcelain` just returns the list of files. How can I get all files with only changed file permissions?

Comment: `$ chmod +x Makefile` then `$ git status --porcelain=2` shows `1 .M N... 100644 100644 100755 76f853af52c9ed30dc420893155b5297123a2ae1 76f853af52c9ed30dc420893155b5297123a2ae1 Makefile` which lists the changed file access modes.

Comment: `git status --porcelain=2` returns `option porcelain takes no value`. Probably because its an older git version. (`git version 1.8.3.1`)

Comment: Okay, let's dig deeper ;-) Please see whether `git diff-files` works for you.